# Adding more music to the Windows Phone 7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

The emulator has something like 3 songs which isn't enough to make sure the song selection code I'm working on will manage more than said 3 songs.

So just wondering if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to add songs to the emulator.
You'll have to use a real device to test this.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose.. They should probably add dummy songs or something in later releases...

Comment: It's a bit annoying as it's possible to add pictures via the `MediaLibrary`. I suspect that adding songs si a bit more complicated though as you'd need to consider artwork, artists, albums, genres, etc. Maybe in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can using an app to do that:

```
Uri file = new Uri("Assets/Happy.mp3", UriKind.Relative);

//copy file to isolated storage
var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile("someSong.mp3");
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(file);
int chunkSize = 4096;
byte[] bytes = new byte[chunkSize];
int byteCount;
while ((byteCount = resource.Stream.Read(bytes, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
{
    fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, byteCount);
}
fileStream.Close();
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SongMetadata metaData = 
    new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SongMetadata();
metaData.AlbumName = "Some Album name";
metaData.ArtistName = "Some Artist Name";
metaData.GenreName = "test";
metaData.Name = "someSongName";

var ml = new MediaLibrary();
Uri songUri = new Uri("someSong.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var song = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong(ml, songUri, metaData, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);
```

Comment: I tried doing this. I am getting an error `The type or namespace name 'PhoneExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`. Also, I am unable to add a reference to `microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.dll` as it is not present. I couldn't get the dll anywhere on internet.

Comment: I can send them to you but I think it's enough that you install Microsoft XNA Game Studio...

Comment: I am developing a windows phone app that plays Audio from the phone's media library. This is my first such attempt. So, sorry for the newbie question, but do I still need to have XNA Game Studio for this purpose?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I am downloading XNA Game Studio.

Comment: Same problem. The latter example uses SongMetadata class and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.songmetadata(v=xnagamestudio.42).aspx) link says it's in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions which I dont have.

Comment: I have also posted [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848978/unable-to-reference-microsoft-xna-framework-media-phoneextensions-dll) regarding this problem.

Comment: I have answered your other question also :D