# Adding a song into music in the Windows Phone Emulator in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sdk, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone 8.0 SDK.
I want to add a song to Music in the emulator for debugging.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not possible
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285868/adding-more-music-to-the-windows-phone-7-emulator?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy a `Happy.mp3` file in your project `Assets` folder
Add the file to the project:
[image][image]
and set the Happy.mp3 `Properties` :

[image: MP3Properties]

Then run this code to copy the song to the MediaLibrary.

```
Uri file = new Uri("Assets/Happy.mp3", UriKind.Relative);

//copy file to isolated storage
var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile("someSong.mp3");
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(file);
int chunkSize = 4096;
byte[] bytes = new byte[chunkSize];
int byteCount;
while ((byteCount = resource.Stream.Read(bytes, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
{
    fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, byteCount);
}
fileStream.Close();
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SongMetadata metaData = 
    new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SongMetadata();
metaData.AlbumName = "Some Album name";
metaData.ArtistName = "Some Artist Name";
metaData.GenreName = "test";
metaData.Name = "someSongName";

var ml = new MediaLibrary();
Uri songUri = new Uri("someSong.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var song = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong(ml, songUri, metaData, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);
```

Comment: Thank you !! But it throws a NullReferenceException at "while ((byteCount = resource.Stream.Read(bytes, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)". What I did was, I put a mp3 named "Happy.mp3" to the Assets folder of my Visual Studio project folder and ran the code. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You must have a song in Assets/Happy.mp3 with it's property set to Copy if newer

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. Why cant I see the Happy.mp3 file I put to the assets folder in the solution explorer of VS ? :)

Comment: You must include it in the project

Comment: Sorry I didnt get it. Do you mean the project folder ?

Comment: Successfull !!!. The thing I have done wrong is not enabling show all files. I could see it clearly after your update. Thank you very much !!!