# Windows Phone application crashes when pausing the current song

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna, microphone

My goal is pausing the currently playing song when the amplitude of the microphone exceeds some value.
But the apps exit suddenly when the amplitude increase that value.
Why is that?
How to fix this?

[What I did was I played a song in music,
 opened this app and press the button and acted a sound that exceed the value.
Then the app exit suddenly]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using U.Resources;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace U
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
    //global variables
    Microphone microphone = Microphone.Default;
    byte[] buffer;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Timer to simulate the XNA Game Studio game loop (Microphone is from XNA Game Studio)
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
        dt.Tick += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };
        dt.Start();

        microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferReady);

    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];
        microphone.Start();
    }

    void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        microphone.GetData(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 2)
        {
            //The value of sample is the amplitude of the signal
            short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[2] { buffer[i], buffer[i + 1] }, 0);
            //getting the absolut value
            if (sample < 0) sample *= (-1);

            //showing the output
             if(sample>1000) pause_music();
        }

    }

    void pause_music() 
    {
        if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing)
        {
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            MediaPlayer.Pause();
        }
    }




}
```

}

Comment: I tested it on a lumia device. It exits the app as I mentioned. I cannot debug it on emulator because I cannot play music on emulator. Is there any other method to debug it ?

Comment: Post the exception you get when the app crashes, please

Comment: How can I see the exception when it runs on a real device instead of emulator ? I am happy if I can debug it on emulator.

Comment: How are you deploying the app?

Comment: on Visual Studio. It does not crash on the emulator since I haven't played any music on it(It seems not possible to play music on emulator)

Comment: Use Visual Studio to deploy the app on your device and you'll get the exception!

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I cannot test it right now. Can I have some ideas why it is crashing please ?

Comment: I've tested it on my device and found the problem. See the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is crashing because it's going StackOverflow!

You should not call `FrameworkDispatcher.Update()` from within `pause_music()` method!
That would just result in another call to `microphone_BufferReady` and then `pause_music` etc etc and your stack overflow is served.

Just remove that line and remember to call `microphone.Stop()` and it will work :)

Comment: Thank you very much Paolo. I'l try it again on my device as you corrected and will state here. I added FrameworkDispatcher.Update() because previously I checked "pause" and "resume" system music with simple interface without microphone thing, but it crashed without the FrameworkDispatcher.Update(). Will it be an issue here ?

Comment: No, it should not be an issue.
Anyway I'd suggest you to read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175122/Making-a-Voice-Recorder-on-Windows-Phone and to use its XNAFrameworkDispatcherService class for your FrameworkDispatcher.Update calls :)

That way you'll never have to worry about it again.

Comment: I found a way to play music on the emulator [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979972/adding-a-song-into-music-in-the-windows-phone-emulator-in-visual-studio-2012/23041512?noredirect=1#comment35204057_23041512). So I tried my above code in the emulator. It worked without crashing. I did not do any change. Why can this happen ?

Comment: I tested it too and it works for me without crashing, to.
I don't know why this happens, but I am quite sure that you should **not** call FrameworkDispatcher.Update() there.

Comment: When the amplitude exceeds the limit I pause the song Thread.sleep(10*1000) and resume the song again. I do microphone.stop() before pause and do microphone.start() after resuming the song. But when I remove the FrameworkDispatcher.Update() from there, it pauses again just after it resumes without no reason and happen it infinitely. But when there is FrameworkDispatcher.Update() it works fine. Why is that ? :)

Comment: It pauses again, I guess, because the microphone_BufferReady method gets called again.
Use the article I have linked before and its XNAFrameworkDispatcherService; after that, do not call FrameworkDispatcher.Udpate anywhere else. Just let it be called by that service class. That should be the right way which stops giving you headaches.

Comment: I tried the code again in a lumia. It worked as expected. Thank you very much !