# How to Save Music file in Windows Phone Emulator?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am creating an app for music player, but in my Emulator there are no music files

So I decided to add few songs in `MediaLibrary`

I wrote following code to add songs:

```
public void addsong()
        {
            try
            {
                Uri songUri = new Uri("../Assets/samplemusic/02 Can't Remember to Forget You (feat. Rihanna).mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                //SaveFileToIsolatedStorage(songUri, "test.mp3");

                MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();

                SongMetadata metadata = new SongMetadata

                {

                    GenreName = "Super Hit Songs",

                    Name = "Song 1",

                    AlbumName = "My Collections",

                    AlbumArtUri = new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)

                };

                MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong(lib, songUri, metadata, SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

but it is not working, I don't know why

[image]
[image]

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Save music files to isolated storage instead of music library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979972/adding-a-song-into-music-in-the-windows-phone-emulator-in-visual-studio-2012?answertab=votes#tab-top

Try this.. Let us know if you face any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer should be enough for what you are trying to do:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23041512/1537726
```

Comment: Perfect, could you help me more bit? can i add 100-200 songs in emulador? via copy/paste to phisical location?

Comment: @vir Nope that's not possible you must do them all through the app

Comment: foreach file in your `Assets/MusicToEmulator/` folder copy to `IsolatedStorage` and then to `MediaLibrary`, but at each step clean the `IsolatedStorage`.

Comment: Thanks , i guess, it is only one way :(