# Unable to reference microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.dll

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, dll, xna, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285868/adding-more-music-to-the-windows-phone-7-emulator/23041528#23041528) answer to add some audio files to the windows phone emulator's media library. But I get the error

> The type or namespace name 'PhoneExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

I am unable to reference microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.dll as it is not present at the location

> C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71

I installed Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0 but still could not find the dll in the system folders.
I tried but couldn't get the dll anywhere on internet.
Here's my code (if it matters)

```
Uri file = new Uri("files/a_wink.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile("a_wink.mp3");
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(file);
int chunkSize = 2000000;
byte[] bytes = new byte[chunkSize];
int byteCount;
while ((byteCount = resource.Stream.Read(bytes, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
    fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, byteCount);
fileStream.Close();
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SongMetadata metaData =
    new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SongMetadata();
metaData.AlbumName = "Some Album name";
metaData.ArtistName = "Some Artist Name";
metaData.GenreName = "test";
metaData.Name = "someSongName";

var ml = new MediaLibrary();
Uri songUri = new Uri("someSong.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var song =
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong(
        ml, songUri, metaData,
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions.SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary
    );
```

**Edit:**
I am using Windows Phone SDK 7.1 on Vista Home Basic.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the library here once you have installed WP8 SDK

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll
```

If you can't install WP8 SDK's
You can find the XNA Framework dlls here:

- [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll](http://robyapps.com/XNA/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll)
- [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll](http://robyapps.com/XNA/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll)
- [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServicesExtensions.dll](http://robyapps.com/XNA/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServicesExtensions.dll)
- [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll](http://robyapps.com/XNA/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll)
- [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll](http://robyapps.com/XNA/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll)

Comment: I don't have `WindowsPhone` folder present in `Framework` folder. Sorry for I haven't mentioned this in the question, but I have Windows Phone SDK 7.1 installed on my Vista.

Comment: Maybe you just need to install it and still work on wp7 project

Comment: +1. Thanks for your answer. But I can't verify it. To install WP SDK 8, I need to purchase and install Windows 7 first. And all this just to test for more than 3 songs in my app. Developing for WP has been so annoying. I am dropping my plan for a Windows app and will stick to the Android one. Thanks.

Comment: @P5Coder I updated my answer to provide links to the dlls so that you don't need to install WP SDK 8

Comment: Yes I saw but microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.dll is not there. Which is the most important, if not the only, dll I need.

Comment: The `microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions` is a namespace inside `MediaLibraryExtensions.dll`